# Python - TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument:

Tags: python

Fourth to last line, I am getting an error message that says (copied below), and I have no idea what I did wrong or how to fix it. :

File "C:/Users/amilosz/PycharmProject/Assignment_2_Project/venv/Assignment_2.py", line 31, in <module>
picked = scramble()
TypeError: scramble() missing 1 required positional argument: 'w'

```
import random

player_points = 0


def pick():
    word_list = ["butter", "boat", "food", "green", "sun", "bone", "chamber", "fox", "charity", "tie", "explorer", "house", "freedom", "bicycle", "book"]
    word_pick = random.choice(word_list)
    return word_pick


player = print(input("Welcome to Word Scramble! You will be given a scrambled word."
                         "Try to guess the correct word, and earn some points!"
                         " To begin, please enter your name: "))


def scramble(w):
    ranw = random.sample(w, len(w))
    scrambled = ''.join(ranw)
    return scrambled


while True:
    picked = scramble()
    scrambled_word = sw(picked)
    print("The scrambled word is: ", scrambled_word)
    player_answer = input("What is this word? ")
```

I am just trying to write a code for a Word Scramble game. Was running perfectly fine until I changed some function names and now it is not running.

Comment: You have defined `scramble()` as a function that takes one argument, `w`.   On the fourth-to-last line, you are calling it without that argument.  I think maybe you meant to say `picked = pick()` rather than `picked = scramble()`,  and then presumably `scrambled_word = scramble(picked)` rather than `scrambled_word = sw(picked)`.   `sw` is undefined I guess.